# Attempting to retrieve a <select>'s .value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this HTML Code/Javascript,

```js
var spellNumber = 0;

function createSpell() {
  var spellOption = document.createElement("option");
  var spellOption2 = document.createElement("option");
  var spellSelect = document.createElement("select");
  var spellLabel = document.createElement("label");
  var spellEnvelope = document.createElement("p");

  spellOption.innerHTML = 'Vanish';
  spellOption.setAttribute('value', 'vanish');
  spellOption2.innerHTML = 'Teleport';
  spellOption2.setAttribute('value', 'teleport');

  spellSelect.setAttribute('id', 'spell');
  spellSelect.setAttribute('name', 'spell');

  spellLabel.setAttribute('for', 'spell');
  spellLabel.innerHTML = '<strong>Spell ' + (spellNumber + 1) + '</strong> = ';

  spellEnvelope.appendChild(spellLabel);
  spellEnvelope.appendChild(spellSelect);
  spellSelect.appendChild(spellOption);
  spellSelect.appendChild(spellOption2);
  document.getElementById("spells").appendChild(spellEnvelope);
  spellNumber += 1;
}
createSpell()
function generateYaml() {
var spellCheck = 1;
for (allSpells = 0; allSpells < spellNumber; allSpells++) {
  var multipleSpell = $("#spell:contains('Spell " + spellCheck + "')").val();
  console.log(multipleSpell);
  spellCheck++
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spells"></div>
<button onClick="createSpell()">Add A Spell</button>
<button id="button" onClick="generateYaml()">Make the Magic Happen</button>
```

And am trying to retrieve the `.value` of the `<select id="spell">` options. However, the console returns an undefined, instead of `vanish` or `teleport`.
Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: use `$.val()` method

Comment: You need to use `val()` as you are operating off of a jQuery object, which does not directly expose properties.

Comment: well why would a label have a value? And you can not have mutltiple elements with the same id.

Comment: I believe the issue now is they are targeting the single parent div, rather than the nested selects that are appended.  The selector is invalid for what they are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well:

- Id should be unique so I added `spellSelect.setAttribute('id', 'spell' + spellNumber);` ( + other rows)
- Also `multipleSpell = $("#spell" + spellCheck).val();`
- And `console.log(multipleSpell);` is called only once at the begining -> you should change it to function too
  `

```js
var spellNumber = 0;

function createSpell() {
  var spellOption = document.createElement("option");
  var spellOption2 = document.createElement("option");
  var spellSelect = document.createElement("select");
  var spellLabel = document.createElement("label");
  var spellEnvelope = document.createElement("p");

  spellOption.innerHTML = 'Vanish';
  spellOption.setAttribute('value', 'vanish');
  spellOption2.innerHTML = 'Teleport';
  spellOption2.setAttribute('value', 'teleport');

  spellSelect.setAttribute('id', 'spell' + spellNumber);
  spellSelect.setAttribute('name', 'spell' + spellNumber);

  spellLabel.setAttribute('for', 'spell' + spellNumber);
  spellLabel.innerHTML = '<strong>Spell ' + (spellNumber + 1) + '</strong> = ';

  spellEnvelope.appendChild(spellLabel);
  spellEnvelope.appendChild(spellSelect);
  spellSelect.appendChild(spellOption);
  spellSelect.appendChild(spellOption2);
  document.getElementById("spells").appendChild(spellEnvelope);
  spellNumber += 1;
}
createSpell()
function generateYaml() {
   var spellCheck = 0;
   for (allSpells = 0; allSpells < spellNumber; allSpells++) {
     var multipleSpell = $("#spell" + spellCheck).val();
     console.log(multipleSpell);
     spellCheck++
   }
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spells"></div>
<button onClick="createSpell()">Add A Spell</button>
<button id="button" onClick="generateYaml()">Make the Magic Happen</button>
```

Comment: It's a typo in the selector.  They should be trying to target the inner selects they are appending to the single div, but they are not.  Not an issue of duplicate ids

Comment: So how do I make them target the selects?

Comment: @DrBracewell i edited the answer, run the snippet (is that what you wanted?) then take a look :)

Comment: I mentioned the issue of duplicated ids because i changed the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
var multipleSpell = $("#spell:contains('Spell " + spellCheck + "')").val();
```

[More info here](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

**Edited:**

Well, i see you are trying to get all select values. Why not try this?

```
function generateYaml() {

    var spellCheck = 1;
    var selects = $("select").each(function (index, element) {
        var value = $(element).val()
        console.log("The value at index %d is %s", index, value);
        spellCheck++
    });

}
```

This way you iterate over all the selects, and get their values inside the loop. Try it here (open the developer console):https://darkcyanpointlessbooleanvalue--parzibyte.repl.co/

Comment: Hmm it still returns `undefined`, I've edited the post with .val() to show you

Comment: Yes, i have fixed the strings

Comment: Nope, still undefined.

Comment: You do realize that you are doing that loop outside of the method, right?  So it's going to run on page load, not when that method happens.  And your spells div starts off empty

Comment: You want to get a select's value or a div value?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to include that that for loop is actually included in a button. I've fixed that in the post, and can you clarify about the empty div? How does that affect anything?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if it is what you want